# Process returns exit code -532462766 in Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, .net

Process code works perfectly in windows 7 but gives exitcode `-532462766` in Windows 8.1. Basically there's an update exe "`IRSAUpdater.exe`" in my application folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\IRSA\IRSATemp` and I am trying to run the exe through c# process. Can anyone explain why it's not working in Windows 8.1? Here is my code:

```
var process = new ProcessStartInfo(
    @"C:\Program Files (x86)\IRSA\IRSATempIRSAUpdater.exe", args);

Process procUpdate = Process.Start(process);
procUpdate.WaitForExit();

if (processToStart.ExitCode != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("IRSA Update Process Error Exit code: {0}",
        processToStart.ExitCode);
}
```

Comment: `-532462766` is `E0434352` in hex, just in case...

Comment: Dont now if this is related to you problem, but the @ in the second line belongs before the "", so write @"C:\Program Files..."

Comment: @UweKeim its not in hex

Comment: @Nidhoegger No that was just a typing issue. In my program, i've used variable instead of this string...so I don't think this is the problem